# Can I display dialog, and say at the same time?

Tags: applescript

I want the user to see some dialog, and hear something at the same time. so something like this

```
say "Hello!"
display dialog "Hello!"
```

Is there any way I can get these to happen at the same time? Everywhere I look, it just says things about different languages, or completely off topic websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the text to speak to the shell, suppress `stdout` and `stderr` and run the command in the background.

```
do shell script "say Hello > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
display dialog "Hello!"
```

Comment: Would you mind clarifying why you suppress `stdout` and `stderr` when `say` doesn't output anything anyway please?